# JavaMail IMAP. I dont get the newest mails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, flags

when i run the code i only get old mails, but i need to get a mail with a special subject, which is a new, unread mail..... what is the problem?

thanks

```
  public static void dumpMail() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, MessagingException, FolderClosedException, SocketTimeoutException {

Properties props = new Properties();
    String username = "ad\\" + "x";
    String password = "y";
    props.put("mail.imaps.host", "z");
    props.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    props.put("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout", "10000");
    props.put("mail.imaps.timeout", "10000");
    props.put("host", "z");
    props.put("user", username);
    props.put("pass", password);

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("z", username, password);

    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
    FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, false);

    Flags recent = new Flags(Flags.Flag.RECENT);
    FlagTerm recentFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(recent, true);

    SearchTerm searchTerm = new AndTerm(unseenFlagTerm, recentFlagTerm);
    Message[] messages = inbox.search(searchTerm);

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if (messages[i].getSubject().contains("Zeiterfassung")) {
        System.out.println(messages[i].getContent());        
        }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that other applications are accessing the same Inbox?  They may be clearing the RECENT flag or setting the SEEN flag.

Try searching for only SEEN == false or only RECENT == true.  For the former, you'll need to mark all the messages SEEN before you search again.

If you really only want to search messages that are new since you last searched, a better approach is to keep track of the last UID you've seen and only consider messages with a larger UID.

Also, note that you can incorporate the Subject search into your SearchTerm and let the server do the work of searching from that Subject.